# How to make two different barTintColor present for one navigationBar in a pop/push transmition

Tags: ios, objective-c

Some normal code looks like this:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:someColor];
}
```

or

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{

    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor: someColor];

}
```

However, this causes the navigation bar suddenly and completely change it's color upon push event occurs. (or upon you drag the left edge of a controller to pop it, which triggers 'viewWillDisappear' method) Is there any way that I can keep both color presenting during the pop animation?

I know weChat can do that...

As the photo below, while the controller at right side is being popped, the light gray background color (maybe background image) of it's navi bar is there, and the black color of the navi bar of the controller at left side is also there.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by making the the navigation bar transparent in both views, and I added the colors I want in the views itself with a rectangular view just for this to use as background color.

here the storyboard:
[image]

and here the final result:
[image]

Some code (make sure you don't hard code the width of the view like in this example):

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
                         forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
UIView *bg = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 60)];
bg.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:bg];
```

And make sure you disable "Adjust ScrollView Insets"
[image]

Comment: Hi, It'll be great if you could pls show me some example code, thanks

Comment: After I tried all other ways, including making a whole set of transmission animation, I found your solution was the most practical one....